# Issue with Firestore Query Ordering - flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

Display a list of items sorted by three criteria: activeStatus, age range, and lastSeen. The most recent items within a specific age range should appear first list && activeStatus must have 'active' value.

I try this, but it shows an error

```
Future<void> _refresh() async {
    var query = FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection("users")
        .where("activeStatus", isEqualTo: "active")
        .where("age", isGreaterThan: lowerValue)
        .where("age", isLessThan: upperValue);
query =
        query.orderBy("lastSeen", descending: true); // Then order by lastSeen

    query = query.orderBy("age", descending: false); // Order by age first
    
    setState(() {
      usersQuery = query;
    });
  }
```

Error -

> [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: 'package:cloud_firestore/src/query.dart': Failed assertion: line 492 pos 13: 'conditionField == orders[0][0]': The initial orderBy() field "[[FieldPath([lastSeen_age]), true]][0][0]" has to be the same as the where() field parameter "FieldPath([age])" when an inequality operator is invoked.

My firestore index:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

As explained in the error message you are actually facing one of the Firestore [limitations](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/order-limit-data#limitations):

> If you include a filter with a range comparison (<, <=, >, >=), your
> first ordering must be on the same field

If you cannot change your data model or screen architecture, one of the options would to sort only by `age` in the query and sort by `lastSeen` in the front-end (i.e. in the Flutter app).

Comment: What if I do it like this? This is working. Is it okay?


var query = FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection("users")
        .where("activeStatus", isEqualTo: "active")
        .where("age", whereIn: [30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 36, 35]);
 
    query =
        query.orderBy("lastSeen", descending: true);

Comment: Yes it is ok if it works and if it ok for you to define the age Array for each specific case.